# How to sum different element nodes in xml to assign value in another node

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have an xml in sql server which is like:

```
<Student version="2">
  <Section name="Report">
    <Glossary>
      <Item name="Some text"</Item>
    </Glossary>
    <InputNumber type="int" min="0" max="100" title="Maths" format="normal" description="Marks obtained in Maths out of 100">
      <Value>70</Value>
    </InputNumber>
    <InputNumber type="int" min="0" max="100" title="Science" format="normal" description="Marks obtained in Science out of 100">
      <Value>60</Value>
    </InputNumber>
    <InputNumber type="int" min="0" max="100" title="English" format="normal" description="Marks obtained in English out of 100">
      <Value>80</Value>
    </InputNumber>
 <InputNumber type="float" min="100" max="100" title="Total " format="normal" description="Total  of all subjects marks added together.">
      <Value/>
    </InputNumber>
    <InputNumber type="int" min="0" max="10000" title="How many students in the class?" format="normal" description="total students>
      <Value>19</Value>
    </InputNumber>
    <InputNumber type="int" min="0" max="100" title="How many subjects are there?" format="normal" description="total subjects">
      <Value>3</Value>
    </InputNumber>
</Section>
<Section>
....
</Section>
</Student>
```

Here, In the value of /Student[1]/Section[1]/InputNumber[4] which is sum of all the marks in all the subject is to be filled which will be 210 in this case.

How can I take sum of values in the nodes: /Student[1]/Section[1]/InputNumber[1], /Student[1]/Section[1]/InputNumber[2], /Student[1]/Section[1]/InputNumber[3] and assign it to /Student[1]/Section[1]/InputNumber[4].

Comment: It would be much easier, if your subject's marks had some kind of tagging (a common attribute?). In this case the total would mention this special tag. The rest was easy... In your sample the **position** seems to be the only marking. Everything before `title="Total"`... What would happen if there are additional elements **before** the first subject? What, if one subject was inserted **after** `Total`?

Comment: Ok, it is an existing xml file which I am working on. So for adding an attribute I need to perform insert and delete operation on node Or there is a way to add attribute?

Comment: Got it. SET @myDoc.modify('             
insert attribute LaborHours {".5" }             
into (/Root/Location[@LocationID=10])[1] ') ;

Answer (score 1):

I guess there will be simple way of doing this, but here is one variant:

```
DECLARE @DataXML XML;

SET @DataXML = '<Student version="2">
    <Section name="Report">
        <Glossary>
            <Item name="Some text"></Item>
        </Glossary>
        <InputNumber type="int" min="0" max="100" title="Maths" format="normal" description="Marks out of 100">
            <Value>70</Value>
        </InputNumber>
        <InputNumber type="int" min="0" max="100" title="Science" format="normal" description="Marks out of 100">
            <Value>60</Value>
        </InputNumber>
        <InputNumber type="int" min="0" max="100" title="English" format="normal" description="Marks out of 100">
            <Value>80</Value>
        </InputNumber>
        <InputNumber type="float" min="100" max="100" title="Total " format="normal" description="Total  of all subjects marks added together.">
            <Value />
        </InputNumber>
        <InputNumber type="int" min="0" max="10000" title="How many students in the class?" format="normal" description="total students">
            <Value>19</Value>
        </InputNumber>
        <InputNumber type="int" min="0" max="100" title="How many subjects are there?" format="normal" description="total subjects">
            <Value>3</Value>
        </InputNumber>
    </Section>
</Student>';


SET @DataXML.modify('insert text{sum(./Student[@version="2"]/Section[@name="Report"]/InputNumber[@description="Marks out of 100"]/Value)} into (./Student[@version="2"]/Section[@name="Report"]/InputNumber[@description="Total  of all subjects marks added together."]/Value)[1]');

SELECT @DataXML;
```

The idea is to insert `text` for this node:

```
(./Student[@version="2"]/Section[@name="Report"]/InputNumber[@description="Total  of all subjects marks added together."]/Value)[1]
```

and the text is simple the some of these ones:

```
sum(./Student[@version="2"]/Section[@name="Report"]/InputNumber[@description="Marks out of 100"]/Value)
```

I don't like selecting the nodes using the description tag value. It will be better if you have another way.

Also, it will be nicer if you have these data normalized in SQL tables and built this `XML` using `FOR XML` clause before it is send to the application.

---

You can filter the nodes for the some like this:

```
SET @DataXML.modify('insert text{sum(./Student[@version="2"]/Section[@name="Report"]/InputNumber[@title="Maths" or @title="Science" or @title="English"]/Value)} into (./Student[@version="2"]/Section[@name="Report"]/InputNumber[@description="Total  of all subjects marks added together."]/Value)[1]');
```

using the titles:

```
(./Student[@version="2"]/Section[@name="Report"]/InputNumber[@title="Maths" or @title="Science" or @title="English"]/Value)
```

It will be better to add a type of the `input` and filter by it - for example add attribute `type=mark`.

Comment: This is an existing db with a table in which one column stores all the respective XML files. For application, I have to fetch data directly from these xml files and send to application. So any problem in this approach?

Comment: @richaverma There is no problem with any approach. Which one to use depends on the business needs. I prefer generating the JSON/XML and send it to the application, because having the data in tables make it easier for me to perform modifications. I am not very comfortable with editing XML variables for example.

Comment: Ok, one mistake I made in writing xml here, the description is not same for all three node. Also updating in my question. Thanks

Comment: @richaverma OK, you can use more complex filtering, but it will be better to add an attribute and select the nodes for the sum using it - it will work for new values as well without modifying the code.